# Obtaining LinkIdType for calculateroute

Tags: here-api

I'm currently trying to use the the [`calculateroute`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) endpoint to avoid certain roads that I specify.

It accepts `avoidLinks` parameter in which a list `LinkIdTypes` can be specified which determines the network links to be avoided when calculating the route.

What I'm having trouble finding is how do I get those `LinkIdType`s, does Here provide an endpoint to query them (specifiying *lat* & *lng*)? or perhaps an endpoint I can use to define my own which then gives me a `LinkIdType` which I can reuse for future calls?

**tl;dr: Where do I get `LinkIdType`s for a specific road?**

Addendum: I am aware of `avoidAreas` but this seems too cumbersome to use since I have to specify a bounding box instead of a road segment.

Comment: @BenRoob This isn't really a question about the code itself but rather a question about the Here API (btw I'm not new on SO, this is an alt account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get linkId by doing a reverse geocode of a lat,lng.

[Exemple of reverse geocode](http://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?app_id=XXXX&app_code=YYYY&prox=LAT,LNG&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1) . 
LinkId is available in the field ReferenceId.

[image]

You can also get the list of linkId of your route with calculateroute using legAttributes=links.

[Exemple of calculate route](http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=XXXXXX&app_code=YYYYY&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&legAttributes=links&maneuverattributes=none&waypoint0=48.78381310475713,2.5028838962316513&waypoint1=48.901980226046504,2.3586220228962986&routeAttributes=legs)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, pretty weird that the Maps API reference doesn't even mention this.